# Derive names of R list elements, but ignore data.frame column names

Tags: r, list, dataframe

#### Desired

is having a R function

```r
listNames = function(l) {
   # return list element names
}
```

that returns all list elements, but ignores the column names of data frames on first level

```r
listNames(a)
[1] "b.df1" "b.e" "c" "df2"
```

from a nested list:

```r
a = list(b = list(df1 = data.frame(col = c(1,2)), e = NULL), c = NULL, df2 = data.frame(c12 = c(1,2),c34 = c(3,4)))
```

### Tried so far

`unlist` returns also data.frame columns. I assume because data.frames are also considered lists

```r
names(unlist(a,recursive = FALSE))
[1] "b.df1"   "b.e"     "df2.c12" "df2.c34"
```

and `names(a)` skips nested elements

```
names(a)
[1] "b"   "c"   "df2"
```

Comment: Are you looking for `names(a)`?

Comment: @MartinGal no, see edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a recursive function stopping when there is no list or a `data.frame`.

```
listNames = function(l) {
  if(!is.list(l) | is.data.frame(l)) TRUE
  else (lapply(l, listNames))
}

names(unlist(listNames(a)))
#[1] "b.df1" "b.e"   "c"     "df2"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using an external package, this can be done with `rrapply::rrapply()`, which extends base `rapply` to avoid recursing into individual data.frame columns.

One possible approach is to include `"data.frame"` in the evaluated `classes` and return the name of each evaluated element, which works for arbitrary levels of nesting:

```
library(rrapply)

rrapply(a, classes = c("ANY", "data.frame"), f = function(x, .xname) .xname, how = "unlist")

#> b.df1   b.e     c   df2 
#> "df1"   "e"   "c" "df2"
```

Comment: Hey Joris, looks good and even though we try to avoid dependencies I appreciate one-liner always!